# Can't install svn on STS

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm trying to install svn on my STS but I'm having some problems as I'm getting a few errors:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.core.nl1,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.m2e.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.mylyn.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.nl1,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.nl1.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.resource.ignore.rules.jdt.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.revision.graph.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.sources,4.0.0.I20160604-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.nl1,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.m2e.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.mylyn.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.nl1,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.nl1.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.resource.ignore.rules.jdt.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.revision.graph.sources,4.0.0.I20160226-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.source,4.0.0.I20160604-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.sources,4.0.0.I20160604-1700
```

I've followed the tutorial in here https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/videos.php but it looks like it's not having it. Is there anything I'm missing? The connector isn't installed as yet because the tutorial says it needs to be installed later (but I even tried when it was installed and it made no difference). My version of STS is this:
Spring Tool Suite

```
Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100339
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)
```

ANy idea?
thanks